# DatePicker display null value

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to display null date value in windows store app DatePicker control?
Following converter doesn't work:-

```
 <DatePicker   Date="{Binding Machine.BasicStartDateTime,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}"/>


public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value!=null && value.ToString() !="")
                {
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
                    return new DateTimeOffset(date);
                }
                DateTimeOffset? dt=null;
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DateTimeOffset? dt = null;
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

The 'BasicStartDateTime' is a string type property and works fine when the value is not null (valid date). In case, the value is null the control shows today's date.

Comment: Define **doesn't work**, and where's the `DatePicker` control?

Comment: @ekad It shows the today's date instead of blank.

Comment: You haven't answered my second question: where's the `DatePicker` control? I don't see any `DatePicker` in the code. How do you set the `DatePicker` value with that code?

Comment: Ok, I added more info to the post.